# Работа с Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

#### Есть стандартное меню дравер, к нему подключается xml с разметкой меню

```
    <menu>
      <item>
      </item>
   </menu>
```

**Как можно изменить положение(  gravity) позицию элемента меню, не прибегая к созданию своей разметки ?**
Например, 3-5 пунктов меню и внизу кнопка,  например настройки. Т.е. пункт **настройки будет привязан к bottom**.

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

В документации не нашел информации по этому поводу...

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "изменить позицию элемента меню"?

Comment: @ ZigZag Задать положение   gravity

Comment: У вас без создания размети это врядли получится. Разве что в JAVA коде, после создания Drawer найти соответствующий пункт, и выставить ему gravity